# How to undo a UV map and editor

Tags: uv

This is about my 4th attempt at UV unwrapping using a masking tool.

As a beginner, I am following a YouTube video to create this paint job on a fuselage.

When I try to start over for practice, I see that the original settings for naming the texture (fuselage texture/fuselage material, resolution, etc) are still active.

How do I completely reset the UV editor and wipe out all settings for Blender 3.1?

[image]

Comment: Reset the settings, as in Reset the GUI?

Comment: Reset all the changes I made to do the above photo. When I try to do this project again, the old settings are still there. Just want to go back to default settings.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "old settings". Not sure if you mean the GUI or the way the UV looks, but the image it's a render, no te UV editor

Comment: Why not start from a new fresh scene?

Comment: Actually, I unknowingly saved the video editor after this project and wasn’t sure how to delete it. Still not sure. When I split the screen to initiate it, it still shows up when I close the project down.

Comment: You mean resetting Blender to its default UI and settings? [Defaults — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/getting_started/configuration/defaults.html#loading-factory-settings)